# What would be the advantages of using ELK for log management over a simple python logging + existing database log table combo?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, elastic-stack

Assuming I have many Python processes running on an automation server such as Jenkins, let's say I want to use Python's native logging module and, other than writing to the Jenkins console or to a log file, I want to store & centralize the logs somewhere.

I thought of using ELK for that, but then I realized that I can just as well create a dedicated log table in an existing database (I'm using Redshift), use something like Grafana for log dashboards/visualization and save myself the trouble of deploying a new system (most of the people in my team are familiar with Redshift but not with ElasticSearch).

Although it sounds straightforward, I feel like I'm not looking at the big picture and that I would be missing some powerful capabilities that components like Logstash were written for the in the first place. What would these capabilities be and how would it be advantageous to use ELK instead of my solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have implemented a full ELK stack in my company in the past year.

The project was huge and took a lot of time to properly implement. The advantages of using ELK and not implementing our own centralized logging solution would be:

1. Not needing to re-invent the wheel- There is already a product that is doing just that. (and the installation part is extremely easy)
2. It is battle tested and can stand huge amount of logs in a short time.
3. As your business and product grows and shift you will need to parse more logs with different structure which will mean DB changes on self built system. logstash will give you endless possibilities of filtering and parsing those new formatted logs.
4. It has Cluster and HA capabilities, and you can scale your logging system vertically and horizontally.
5. Very easy to maintain and change over time.
6. It can send the needed output to a variety of products including Zabbix, Grafana, elasticsearch and many more.
7. Kibana will give you ability to view the logs, build graphs and dashboards, alerts and more...

The options with ELK are really endless and the more I work with it, the more I find new ways it can help me. not just from viewing logs on distributed remote server systems, but also security alerts and SLA graphs and many other insights.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I'll give it a try then. :)

Comment: No problem. Good Luck! :)